# yII2:Date filter how to in Gridview

Tags: php, gridview, filter, yii2

Well I can filter on any fields including the column from related fields, but I wonder how I can filter on date fields.

One solution I came across is date-picker for filter, I have not tested this, but my requirement is little different.

for example I have duplicated the `datetime` column in gridview and formatted it like

```
[
    'attribute'=>'discharge_date',
    'format'=>['DateTime','php:M']
],
```

So that the column will show only months.The column is showing the months correctly.

Now I want to filter by month on this column.
Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

I did try like this

```
[
     'attribute'=>'discharge_date',
     'value'=>'discharge_date',
     'filter' => ['2015-01'=>'Jan','2015-02'=>'Feb','2015-03'=>'Mar'],
     'format'=>['DateTime','php:M']

  ],
```

This works fine, but here the year is being hard-coded, which I don't want.
I know this is not the proper way.
Thanks

Comment: And the question is ??

Comment: @soju - The question is how I can create a drop-down filter for months in the gridview

Comment: So what did you try ??

Comment: @soju - question updated.

Answer (score 6):

You can use kartik Date Range Picker for that :

1.check this out : https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-date-range

Implementation

1.In your view :  use kartik\daterange\DateRangePicker;

2.If you are using grid view

- Add this code in attribute

  ```
  [
   'attribute'=>'Date',
   'label'=>'Date',
   'format'=>'text',
   'filter'=> '<div class="drp-container input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>'.
    DateRangePicker::widget([
       'name'  => 'ItemOrderSearch[created_at]',
       'pluginOptions'=>[ 
                'locale'=>[
                'separator'=>'to',
                ],
        'opens'=>'right'
            ] 
        ]) . '</div>',
  'content'=>function($data){
             return Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime($data['created_at'], "php:d-M-Y");
     }
  ]
  ```

3.Pick the date in your Controller parse date like

```
    $date = explode( 'to', $item['date']) // Temporary store into variable as an array
    // $date[0]  =>  12/07/2015 - from date
    // $date[1]  =>  12/10/2015 - to date
```

4.Pass it to your Model and execute query .

Comment: Do not forget to add your bootstrap version [3, 4, 5] into config/params.php:
    `return [
    ...
      'bsVersion' => '4.x',
    ....
];`